# Python Pandas Stem and leaf plot

Tags: python, plot, pandas, latex

I need to export a stem and leaf plot from a data frame to latex, is that possible with Pandas, and if not, how can I do it ?

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset and a desired output?  Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655321/is-there-a-pandas-function-for-creating-a-stem-and-leaf-plot

Answer (score 1):

I have answer the question at here [Is there a pandas function for creating a stem and leaf plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655321/is-there-a-pandas-function-for-creating-a-stem-and-leaf-plot/45656792#45656792)

The result like 
[image]

Comment: you better flag the question for being a duplicate instead of copying your answer around on multiple questions.

Comment: When i answer the question, there are no answer for both question. So I just give a link to another question.

Comment: Now I have flagged this question duplicated. Thank you for reminding me。